# Eclipse on Mac vs Windows?

Tags: java

Basically, at my University, we've been given a Finch Robot to work with and help us develop our Java programming skills. However, I have a slight problem. The Uni uses Windows machines and I use a Mac, and basically we've been given pre-written code to test out our Finch Robot. When I copy and paste the code in the WIndows machine, Eclipse gives me no errors whatsoever, and I can go ahead and test the Robot out, but when I attempt the same thing on the Mac, I get 30 errors!! I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code (I've pasted the errors below the code):

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;

public class DoesMyFinchWork 
   {
//This value is the time for most of the tests in milliseconds, 1000 = 1 second
//Change this value if the tests are too long or short
final private static int testtime = 5000;
//This is the Finch object
private static Finch myf = null;
//This is the starting point of the testing program
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    String s = "";
    //'myf' is the name of our Finch object
    //This will used throughout the program to control your Finch and report it's status  
    myf = new Finch();
    do
    {
        //Run the menu until quit or cancel is selected
        s = FinchMenu();
        if (s == "Light Test") RunLightTest(s);
        if (s == "Tilt Test") RunTiltTest(s);
        if (s == "Tap Test") RunTapTest(s);
        if (s == "Temperature Test") RunTemperatureTest(s);
        if (s == "Obstacle Test") RunObstacleTest(s);
        if (s == "Acceleration Test") RunAccelerationTest(s);
        if (s == "Left Wheel Test") RunLeftWheelTest(s);
        if (s == "Right Wheel Test") RunRightWheelTest(s);
        if (s == "Buzzer Test") RunBuzzerTest(s);
        if (s == "Nose Test") RunNoseTest(s);
    } while (s != "Quit"); 
    System.out.println("Exiting DoesMyFinchWork...");
    myf.quit();
}
//This creates the Finch menu
private static String FinchMenu()
{
    Object[] possibilities = {"Light Test", "Tilt Test","Tap Test","Temperature Test", "Obstacle Test","Acceleration Test","Left Wheel Test","Right Wheel Test","Buzzer Test","Nose Test","Quit"};
    String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Dr Swift's Splendid Finch Test\n++++++++++++++++++++++++\nChoose a test from:\n\n","Week Zero Laboratory",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,possibilities,"Light Test");
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) s = "Quit";
    return(s);
}
//Run the light sensor test
//Displays the left and then the right sensor output
private static void RunLightTest(String s)
{
    System.out.println("\n"+"Running: "+s+"\n");
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - before < testtime)
    {
        System.out.println(myf.getLeftLightSensor() + " " + myf.getRightLightSensor());
    }
}
//Run the Tilt Test
//Displays:
//1) Is the beak down?
//2) Is the beak up?
//3) Is the Finch level?
//4) Is the Finch upside down?
//5) Is the Finch's left wing down?
//6) Is the Finch's right wing down?
private static void RunTiltTest(String s)
{
    System.out.println("\n"+"Running: "+s+"\n");
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - before < testtime)
    {
        System.out.println(myf.isBeakDown() + " " + myf.isBeakUp() + " " + myf.isFinchLevel() + " " + myf.isFinchUpsideDown() + " " + myf.isLeftWingDown() + " " + myf.isRightWingDown());
    }
}
//Run the tap test
//Displays if the Finch has been tapped
private static void RunTapTest(String s)
{
    System.out.println("\n"+"Running: "+s+"\n");
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - before < testtime)
    {
        System.out.println(myf.isTapped());
    }
}
//Run the temperature test
//Displays the current temperature in degrees Celsius
private static void RunTemperatureTest(String s)
{
    System.out.println("\n"+"Running: "+s+"\n");
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - before < testtime)
    {
        System.out.println(myf.getTemperature());
    }
}
//Run the obstacle sensor test
//Displays if there is an obstacle left and right of the Finch
private static void RunObstacleTest(String s)
{
    System.out.println("\n"+"Running: "+s+"\n");
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - before < testtime)
    {
        System.out.println(myf.isObstacleLeftSide() + " " + myf.isObstacleRightSide());
    }
}
//Run the acceleration sensor test
//Displays is the Finch is being shaken, and then the acceleration in the X, Y and Z planes
private static void RunAccelerationTest(String s)
{
    System.out.println("\n"+"Running: "+s+"\n");
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - before < testtime)
    {
        System.out.println(myf.isShaken()+ " " + myf.getXAcceleration() + " " + myf.getYAcceleration()+ " " + myf.getZAcceleration());
    }
}
//Run the left wheel test
//Move the left wheel forward and backwards
private static void RunLeftWheelTest(String s)
{
    System.out.println("\n"+"Running: "+s+"\n");
    myf.setWheelVelocities(255,0,testtime/2);
    myf.setWheelVelocities(-255,0,testtime/2);
}
//Run the right wheel test
//Move the right wheel forward and backwards
private static void RunRightWheelTest(String s)
{
    System.out.println("\n"+"Running: "+s+"\n");
    myf.setWheelVelocities(0,255,testtime/2);
    myf.setWheelVelocities(0,-255,testtime/2);
}
//Sound the buzzer for a number of different frequencies
private static void RunBuzzerTest(String s)
{
    System.out.println("\n"+"Running: "+s+"\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=5000;i+=10)
    {
        myf.buzz(i,10);
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() - before < 10)
        {
            //Do nothing...
        }
    }
}
//Flash the Finch's nose red, green and blue
//Then flash it randomly
private static void RunNoseTest(String s)
{
    System.out.println("\n"+"Running: "+s+"\n");
    for(int r=0;r<=255;r+=5)
    {
        myf.setLED(r,0,0,10);
    }
    for(int g=0;g<=255;g+=5)
    {
        myf.setLED(0,g,0,10);
    }
    for(int b=0;b<=255;b+=5)
    {
        myf.setLED(0,0,b,10);
    }
    Random rand = new Random();
    rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for(int i=0;i<50;++i)
    {
        int r = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 255);
        int g = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 255);
        int b = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 255);
        myf.setLED(r,g,b,5);
    }
}
```

}

Here are some of the errors (All 30 errors say 'Finch cannot be resolved to a type'):

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Finch cannot be resolved to a type  DoesMyFinchWork.java    /DoesMyFinchWork/src    line 169    Java
Problem          
Finch cannot be resolved to a type  DoesMyFinchWork.java    /DoesMyFinchWork/src    line 165    Java   
Problem
Finch cannot be resolved to a type  DoesMyFinchWork.java    /DoesMyFinchWork/src    line 161    Java  
Problem
Finch cannot be resolved to a type  DoesMyFinchWork.java    /DoesMyFinchWork/src    line 146    Java
```

Thanks a-lot for your help!

Comment: I suspect you are not including the library which has `edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch` in it. At school this may have been done for you.

Comment: Comparisons of the form `s == "Light Test"` are not likely to give you the result you seek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse just find the jar of Finch, the copy-paste it in a folder of your project (hopefully you have a lib folder), the right-click on that file Build Path > Add to Build Path

and that should solve the problem.

Comment: also if you want to compare strings i suggest you to use:

("Light Test".equals(s))

this is because of the possibility that s is a null.

if you write:

    (s.equals("anithing"))

and s is null, the program will throw a NullPointerException.

BTW, it's a good behavior never to use "==" as string comparator

Comment: I've downloaded some files from the Finch robot website, and there's a finch.jar file there. Should I paste this in the source file for the eclipse project? Then what after that? Thanks.I don't understand how to build path.

Comment: Ah, your solution was the one that worked! I just did it, thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm happy to help you with my answer. As you saw, there is no need to "build path", the build path is only the path where eclipse look for any non-standard class.
If you add a jar to the build path, eclipse look also inside that jar, expanding your avaible classes.
have a nice day in programming ;)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Windows machine already has some configuration done so that it knows where to find this `Finch` class, and your Mac doesn't. Fairly sure the Windows vs. Mac thing is a red herring here: if you went and found another (unconfigured) Windows machine, it won't work.

You probably need to download a library that has the `Finch` class and then configure Eclipse on where to find it. The best place to get this information is probably going to be in the class notes/website. If those don't have it, then just ask the professor.

Comment: Thanks, I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT: Oh, darn. Didn't read the exact question... but if you have problems later...)

Try replacing

> (s == "Light Test")

with

> (s.equals("Light Test"))

and so on.

Possibly the 'JOptionPane.showInputDialog' is implemented in different code on the different platforms. For '==' to work, the dialog must return the *same* String object as is found in the possibilities parameter send in (which need to be 'interned' too, but I think it does intern literals). HTH.

Comment: Also, it'd be better to have names for your 'selectors', to avoid misspelling them. E.g. static String LIGHT_TEST = "Light Test"; aso. Try the "Extract Constant" refactoring alternative.